# Can jquery be deferred without errors?

Tags: jquery, deferred

In the script below, I'm getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error as long as the jQuery.js is included with the defer attribute. It makes no difference that the inline script that is calling the jQuery object is also deferred.

I'm trying to defer the script in order to speed page rendering.

Is it possible to defer jQuery without errors like this?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery defer test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <p>content goes here...</p>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts.jquery.js' defer='defer'></script>
    <script defer='defer'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert('deferred');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, putting the `script` tag in the body makes it load after the rest of the content, so in theory, you wouldn't need defer. Or it at least doesn't block the loading of body content like it would in `head`.

Comment: Your second script block is not actually deferred: [The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer)

Answer (score 2):

The defer attribute only affects external scripts. So your inline javascript will always execute before the external jQuery resource.

From http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer

`The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present.`

Unfortunately for most sites, since they need access to `jQuery(function() {})` to init after DOM ready it almost forces you to load jQuery in the head. This is one prime reason to serve jQuery from the external Google CDN since there is a chance it is already cached by your user (from another site), and it will likely be much faster delivery time than your own web server.

There are a couple ways to get around this such as registering your own temp `jQuery` object simply to store your dom ready functions, but it has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defer` but only for external scripts !